# Prevent object from saving under certain conditions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to prevent a save from occurring under certain conditions.

For example, I create a new "request" object when a user sends a friend request to another user. However, I want to prevent the creation of this object if a "request" between those users already exists.

Previously with Parse, there was a beforeSave function. This allowed me to prevent a save from occurring on the server-side if certain conditions were true.

How can I conditionally allow / disallow the saving of data under certain conditions?

Comment: I'm still unsure of how to go about this

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you're trying to accomplish with this beforeSave function but it sounds an awful lot like firebases .validate in the rules. See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/#section-validation

Comment: My conditions need to be dynamic, unlike it would be with .validate in rules. I need to check for data dynamically (i.e. are there any 'Request' objects in my database that contain both user A and user B), as opposed to a simple rule